# How to determine if a vector field is gradient or not?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

In determining if a vector field is gradient or not we check if higher partial derivatives with respect to opposite variables are equal, that is we check if fxy=fyx. But isn't it true for every function?
I am new to partial derivatives and gradients, fields and all so sorry if my question looks stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^1$ vector field, where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. If it holds that

$$\forall (x,y)\in \Omega : \partial_1f_2(x,y)=\partial_2f_1(x,y),$$

**and $\Omega$ is simply connected**, then $f$ is conservative. Now for the other direction, we can drop the requirement of simple connectedness, as if $f$ is conservative, then it always holds that

$$\forall (x,y)\in \Omega : \partial_1f_2(x,y)=\partial_2f_1(x,y).$$